# MKAnnotationView image with rotation

Tags: objective-c, uiview, rotation, uiimage, mkannotationview

i would like add `UIView` to `MKAnnotationView` as image. But first I wanna rotation by degrees `UIView` and then add new `UIImage` to `UIVIew`. Can you help me? I tried but UIView never rotate.

```
UIView *pinView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 63)];
pinView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IconMapPin"]];
pinView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(self.heading));

UIImage *pinImage = [self imageFromUIView:pinView];    
annotationView.image = pinImage;
```

Method convert UIView to UIImage

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromUIView:(UIView*)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this,

```
pinView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(self.heading));
```

Add this,

```
pinImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(self.heading));
```

After this,

```
UIImage *pinImage = [self imageFromUIView:pinView];
```

So final code will be,

```
UIView *pinView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 63)];
pinView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IconMapPin"]];


UIImage *pinImage = [self imageFromUIView:pinView]; 
pinImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(self.heading));
annotationView.image = pinImage;
```